# How to execute the "help" Linux command on Android?

Tags: android, linux, shell, process, terminal

I would like to run a command like `am -help` and get usage information for that command. However, the `-help` parameter does not seem to work on the Process Runtime. How to make this work?

```
cmd1[0] = "/system/bin/sh";
cmd1[1] = "-c";
cmd1[2] = "/system/bin/am -help"  //I want to do sth like this
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd1);
```

The command works without the `-help`. Is there any way of getting Android Shell commmands' usage information and/or syntaxes? 
**Note that if I don't send `am -help` and just send the command `am` then it automatically returns usage information for that command. Is there any way to invoke that response in any other way?**

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/system/bin/sh
curl -s http://man.he.net/?topic=$1\&section=all | tail -n +10 | head -n -9
```

save this in xbin (lets call it hlp.sh) then just `hlp.sh cat`, you will have help documentation for cat ..
you just need install curl first & also need internet connection ..

Answer (score -1):

I hope I haven't misunderstood what it is you are trying to do. But have you heard of the man command? For example if you wanted to run gparted you could enter `man gparted` and get the documentation on the program. `--help` is not as thorough as the information you'll find in a man page.

You do not need to root to use the `man` command.

**EDIT**: My bad. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2149/where-can-i-find-documentation-for-shell-commands I don't think you can use the man command on Android. That sucks.
Check that link though, there are some interesting answers.