# Android shell command options explained

Tags: android, shell, command-line, grep

I am tinkering with Android developing. Using
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS,
Android Studio 3.0,
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32.

I meant to get a dump of file sizes with

```
$ adb shell
shell@j7elte:/ $ uname -a                                                      
Linux localhost 3.10.61-10026643 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Feb 14 06:53:29 KST 2017 armv8l
shell@j7elte:/ $ du -n -d 1 | grep -i Permission
```

using `grep -i` to filter out lines with `Permission denied`. But neither `-i` or `--invert-match` work.

My two questions are:

**For this specific case, what would the appropriate option be? (equivalent to `--invert-match`)**

**In general, how can I get the list of options with a description, for shell commands? I am used to `grep --help`, e.g., but it does not work. There is no `man` or `info` either.**

Answer (score 0):

The set of shell commands used by Android seems to be `toolbox`.
Information on it seems to be not centralized (which seems *obscure* to me), but one could search and find pieces of information around, e.g.

http://www.all-things-android.com/content/android-toolbox-command-reference

For the particular case of `grep`, [this](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=grep) seems to be the applicable man page.

For "intensive" use of the command line, [BusyBox](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) is generally recommended as a replacement for `toolbox`.

Credits / Related:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2149/where-can-i-find-documentation-for-shell-commands

[How can I get information from the shell about commands available in Android shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647014/how-can-i-get-information-from-the-shell-about-commands-available-in-android-she)

[How to execute the "help" Linux command on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41498651/how-to-execute-the-help-linux-command-on-android)

https://android.stackexchange.com/a/2153/81584

https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/wiki/Android-Shell-Command-Reference

Answer (score 0):

I guess this may vary between Android versions. On the device I have at hand right now (Samsung Galaxy S5) grep lists `-v` option (invert search) as valid but this does not work apparently:

```
shell@klte:/ $ grep
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoPqRSsUVvwxZz] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
    [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
    [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
    [pattern] [file ...]

shell@klte:/ $ df | grep -v 'Permission'                                     
/mnt/secure/asec: Permission denied
[snipped]
```

Some claim Android grep [implementation is from NetBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=grep&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=NetBSD+7.1&arch=default&format=html) but it's buggy beyond anything but most basic filters.

Answer (score -1):

yes. i do not think that the android shell is a terminal so it dosent have options like grep, nano, man, or info. Those can be found in a terminal. A fix for your situation might be UxTerm, try and download it from the android store

Comment: The shell in Android is similar to many others. It has builtin and external commands. In particular, it typically has `grep` available. But I do not know the details on the options for it.